# Cordova Tools Update 1 RC Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, configuration

After updating Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update RC 1, cannot build package from a project. 
After clicking Create - nothing happens... Getting this on output:

> 1>  ------ Copying appx packages to output location 1>  ------ No 1> 
>   ------ Copying appx packages to output location 1>  ------ No packageOutputPath is specified for the project. Nothing to copy.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========is specified for the project. Nothing to copy.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

- I've published packages before, with the same project successfully though.

Where can I specify the packageOutputPath in my project??

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`<vs:packageOutputPath>C:\ourpath\</vs:packageOutputPath>`
to **config.xml** file.