# Cordova Tools Downgrade Update

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, updates

After the latest Cordova Tools Update, I've got many problems with my already running project:

1. I cannot publish a package :
   [Cordova Tools Update 1 RC Visual Studio Community 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755302/cordova-tools-update-1-rc-visual-studio-community-2015)
2. Svgs that used to be loaded to html DOM currently marked as unsafe. I can fix it but its annoying...

Is there a way to Downgrade Cordova Tools in Visual Studio 2015, without repair for all Visual Studio?

Comment: I've looked at the blog, didn't find something that relevant for version downgrading...

Comment: Are you talking about Cordova version or Cordova tools version for vs?

Comment: I think that you didn't understand the issue here. My problem is not with Cordova version. My problem is with Cordova Tools which is an extension (.VSIX)  for my IDE (Visual Studio). The blog that you've posted isn't relevant at all.

Comment: No, you are wrong. You see, Cordova tools does have something to do with Cordova - since it is a "Cordova tools"  for cordova app development. I really don't understand what are you trying to accomplish with this argument...

Comment: You've posted an irrelevant url as an answer, then you told me that I have aversion for reading, afterwards you said that my question and my tags are about different subjects. You just keep on talking nonsense instead of answering the question or moving on, since you cannot answer it.

Comment: Alright. Best of Luck. I recommend you see a movie, or get out of the house - or where you are self-confined to.

Comment: Thanks fir the advice, I'll use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know this question is a little bit old, but I think I can help with my experience for someone else experiencing the same problem.

when you update tools for apache cordova, in order to publish your app or even to make it able to install into another physical device, it requires that you create a new project using the update you have, and then copy the www folder and install the plugins again; otherwise it will say to you that app was not installed without providing any further detail.

TACO is a great tool, but it needs some work. At this moment I am using the update 5 which I've found it has some stability issues that weren't there in the update 4, especially with some basic plugins. Unfortunately I haven't found yet a reasonable way to downgrade the tool. If you decide to install any update, I recommend to save a copy of the tool's files before installing it.